# Code stopped working for no reason. Throwing up a Missing member Exception...why?

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, error-handling

My code stopped working out of nowhere. I am getting this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Public member 'replace' on type 'Double' not found.
Errors out at this line "rCell.Value = rCell.Value.replace("PO", "")"

Here is my Code:

```
    Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO.Directory
'Before you add this reference to your project,
' you need to install Microsoft Office and find last version of this file.
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.word
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions


'=========================================================================ADDRESS FIXER===========================================================================
Public Class Form1

    Public Address2Range As String
    Public PoBoxFirst As String
    Public NewAddress As String
    Public rCell As Excel.Range
    Public NewFirstHalf As String



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        '------------------------------------------------------------------------Browse to Data File--------------------------------------------------------
        Dim eXe As String = "C:\WORK\CHRIS_DATA_NOTES\BadAdds\BadAdds.xlsx"
        '------------------------------------------------------------------Get the path they want to process
        'Using tmpDlg As New OpenFileDialog
        '    tmpDlg.FileName = "C:\WORK\CHRIS_DATA_NOTES\BadAdds"
        '    While eXe Is Nothing
        '        If tmpDlg.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        '            eXe = tmpDlg.FileName
        '        Else
        '            MsgBox("Please Select something.")
        '            Exit Sub
        '        End If
        '    End While
        'End Using

        'MsgBox(eXe)

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(eXe)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")



        Dim eColumn As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E1559")
        ' Dim rCell As Excel.Range

        '--------------------------------------------------------------Fixes PO Boxes-------------------------------------------------------------
        For Each rCell In eColumn


            If rCell.Value = "" Then
                'Application.Exit()
            Else

                Dim PoBox
                Dim PoBoxSearch = {"PO BOX", "P.O.", "O Box", "P0", "PO", "P.O. BOX", "Pox", "P 0", "P O ", "Pob", "PO B", "PO 8", "P0 B", "P O B", "P0B", "PO8", "P0B", "P OB", "PX", "POX", "PBX", "P0X", "PBOX", "P0BX", "PU", "O B"}
                Dim PoList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(PoBoxSearch)
                PoBox = rCell.Value.ToString()
                    PoBoxFirst = PoBox.Substring(0, 1)

                    If PoBoxFirst <> "p" Then
                        rCell.Value = rCell.Value.replace("Box", "")
                        rCell.Value = rCell.Value.replace("PO", "")
                    End If

                    For Each value In PoList

                        If PoBox.contains(value) Then

                            Dim Address As String
                            Address = rCell.Value.ToString()

                            Dim arySpaceFinder() As String
                            arySpaceFinder = Address.Split(" ")

                            'MsgBox(arySpaceFinder.Last())

                            If Char.IsLetter(arySpaceFinder.Last()) = True Then
                                'MsgBox("Has Letter")
                                ' MsgBox(arySpaceFinder.Last())
                                rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder.Last().Replace("I", "1")
                                rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder.Last().Replace("O", "0")
                            rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder.Last().Replace("X", "")
                            rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder.Last().Replace("U", "O")
                        Else

                                'rCell.Value = "PO Box " & Address.Replace("PO", "").Replace("Box", "")
                                rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder(0)
                            End If

                        rCell.Value = "PO Box " & arySpaceFinder.Last().Replace("I", "1").Replace("O", "0").Replace("X", "").Replace("Pob", "").Replace("U", "O")


                    End If
                    Next
                End If

        Next rCell


        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\WORK\CHRIS_DATA_NOTES\BadAdds\Box_NEW.xlsx")
        xlApp.Quit()
        'Application.Exit()

    End Sub
```

Comment: `rCell.Value.ToString().Replace(...your parameters here...)`?

Comment: I saw that fix on the web, but it was working before why would it stop?

Comment: ...because up till now all your values had been non-numeric ?

Comment: Nope! Been using numbers this whole time.

Comment: Well something must've changed.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a try Statement

```
         Try
            If PoBoxFirst <> "p" Then
                rCell.Value = rCell.Value.replace("Box", "")
                rCell.Value = rCell.Value.replace("PO", "")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```